# Eclipse: Enable line wrap in inspect window

Tags: eclipse, inspect, word-wrap

When I used to debug my Java application with my old workspace then the popup window that appears when inspecting expressions displayed the expression's content. If this content was larger than the window's width then it inserted a line break.

Now, with my new workspace, a horizontal scroll bar appears, instead. I'd like to enable this word wrap feature again but cannot find the concerning setting.

Do you know what I mean? How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see here](http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/)  you can get the solution here.It is better to visit that link instead of explaining me.

Comment: Thanks for your hint!

Nevertheless, I found the setting's location, now:

Open the Variables View, right click into the variable preview area, and check "Wrap Text".